# facebookclient.post() or .posttaskasync() with .net sdk returns invalid parameter when trying to post a link

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've had this working in a previous version of my application and I tried using the old code, but I think the new sdk has something different going on.  I'm simply trying to post a link (that includes an image) to my wall and receiving an "Invalid Parameter" response.

Here is the relevant code (I've also tried PostTaskAsync()...same result):

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            var postParams = new
            {
                name = "the name",
                caption = "the caption",
                description = "the description",
                link = "http://www.example.com/",
                picture = "http://www.example.com/uploadedimages/myimage.jpg"
            };
            client.Post("me/feed", postParams);
```

I've tried substituting the object with a Dictionary with the same result.  I've tried substituting object with dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); with the same result.

If I post the object with just { message = "this is a test message" } it posts fine so I know that I have permissions to post on my wall.  Something just isn't jiving when I try to post the link with the image.  I also tried urlencoding the link and the image url and received a different error indicating that the "link/picture URL is not properly formatted".

I stripped out all of the parameters thinking one of them was no longer supported, but still no dice.

Here is the exact exception being thrown:

> Facebook.FacebookApiException: (FacebookApiException - #100) Invalid
>   parameter    at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper
>   httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean
>   containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)    at
>   Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object
>   parameters, Type resultType)    at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String
>   path, Object parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted out.  It turns out the link and the image url have to be in the same domain as the app you're using to post.

EDIT: just to clarify.  The domain has to be included in your app's config section (on Facebook) in the "App domains" section at the top.